# GIT pull asks for root password

Tags: git, config, git-pull

I just inherit this web developers repo. The issue I am having is that I ssh into the server with my username but there is one repo that asks me for the `root` password instead of my password. Now, I know the root password but it is not something I want to share with other developers. Why is this? Here is what I get, so as you can see it says `root@gitserver's password:` instead of `myusername@gitserver's password:`

```
[myusername@server]$ git pull
root@gitserver's password: 
Already up-to-date.
[myusername@server]$
```

Comment: What does `git config remote.origin.url` tell you?

Comment: it says` root@gitserver:/repo/server.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does git config remote.origin.url tell you? – Keith Thompson 9 mins ago
>
> it says `root@gitserver:/repo/server.git` – Tavo 40 secs ago

That repository is configured to log into the remote as root. It's not your local root password it wants, but the root password on `gitserver`.

Somebody probably cloned that repository as root.  Naughty.  One should never be logged in as root for exactly this reason, you might forget and do things as root.  Only use `sudo` so you have to actively choose to run commands as root.  It's probably owned by root, too, so you may not be able to write to it.

To change the remote user, change the remote URL using [`git-remote`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

```
git remote set-url origin myusername@gitserver:/repo/server.git
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @schwern